# More information about Custom Webcontrols?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

Where I currently work we use a lot of hand made custom web controls for things like dropdown lists, auto-complete boxes, etc. and while I have added things to these controls I never really felt like I completely understood what the heck I was doing.

So, my question, are there any good books out there that might help me understand / build some custom webcontrols?

My environment: .net, c# 3.0, linq, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some good links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020430.htm
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/BuildingGroupBoxControl.aspx

Developing server controls is a really good way to learn more about the ASP.NET life cycle as well.